# When will a useable universal quantum computer first be realised?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

Ideally with the reference to the type of technology, when do experts predict a small universal quantum computer of a couple hundred qubits will be developed?

From my reading the leading techology is superconducting qubits, with spins in semiconductors being the next most likely. I've seen a handful of researches predict this being obtainable in 10 years, with others being less bullish.